# python regular expression splitting a string by all combinations of string starting with vowel

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall

problem
split a string by all combination where in each sub string starts with a vowels. For example a string like 
BANANA need to be split into ANANA, ANAN, ANA, AN, A, ANA, AN, A, A

What I tried

```
import re
data_k=re.findall(r'(?=([AEIOU].*))','BANANA')
data_2=[s[:i] for s in data_k for i in range(1,len(s)+1)]
data_2
```

Do we have any faster method to do this , for large string they are giving me memory error, especially the second operation where I split each value in list.

Comment: Are you looking for any solution or just ones that employ a regular expression? If the former, you should rephrase your question, including the title.

Comment: I was looking for a solution using regular expression

Comment: I wrote a short [Ruby script](http://tpcg.io/qH6Zd5T6) to do that, though if does not make use of a regular expression. The algorithm should be clear, so if you are interested it should be easily translatable to Python.

Comment: Python regex alone cannot do this. Use a combination of a regex and loop to get all possible string substrings. See [demo](https://ideone.com/igBayQ) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630994/3832970). But you do not need a regex here, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution without regular expression (but it only gives numbers of substrings in that string staring with vowel because If we try to get all combination then we will ends up with memory error for large strings.) . 
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiA3j.jpg)!